# How to apply kmeans for parquet file?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, k-means

[image: parquet file]

I want to apply k-means for my parquet file.but error appear .

edited

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2

code

```
val Data = sqlContext.read.parquet("/usr/local/spark/dataset/norm")
val parsedData = Data.rdd.map(s => Vectors.dense(s.getDouble(1),s.getDouble(2))).cache()

import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans 
val numClusters = 30
val numIteration = 1
 val userClusterModel = KMeans.train(parsedData, numClusters, numIteration)
val userfeature1 = parsedData.first 
val userCost = userClusterModel.computeCost(parsedData)
println("WSSSE for users: " + userCost)
```

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    val parsedData = Data.rdd.map(s => Vectors.dense(s.getInt(0),s.getDouble(1))).cache()
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are using https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-clustering.html#k-means as a reference to build your K-Means model.

In the example

```
val data = sc.textFile("data/mllib/kmeans_data.txt")
val parsedData = data.map(s => Vectors.dense(s.split(' ').map(_.toDouble))).cache()
```

`data` is of type `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD` In your case `sqlContext.read.parquet` is of type `DataFrame`. Therefore you would have to convert the dataframe to RDD to perform the split operation

To convert from Dataframe to RDD you can use the below sample as reference

```
val rows: RDD[Row] = df.rdd
```

Comment: I convert data  from Dataframe to RDD but error still appear.

Comment: Can you update your question with the updated code sample?